# How i block all websites except gmail & google using mikrotik

Tags: networking, router, mikrotik

I've tried many tutorial how to block any website and except some website.

I can block Website except Google, Youtube, drive.google, google Document (Gsuite Solutions) and Gmail in Bridge-HIS interface.

I can access to website in Allowed Websites & Gmail loader,

! But can't access to **Gmail inbox.**

**This my screenshot & config :**

add chain=forward protocol=tcp dst-port=25,443,465,587,2525 In. Interface=Bridge-HIS action=drop

add chain=forward protocol=tcp dst-port=25,443,465,587,2525 In. Interface=Bridge-HIS Dst-address-list="Allowed Websites" action=accept

Bridge Interfaces https://i.ibb.co/5j4LtV2/Untitled2.png

Address List (Allowed Websites) https://i.ibb.co/PG6sbLd/Untitled3.png"

Firewall Rule Accept https://i.ibb.co/HBG8jqv/firewall-rule-accept.png

Firewall Rule Drop https://i.ibb.co/kynF2rL/firewall-rule-drop.png

Gmail Loader https://i.ibb.co/BKT4HhH/Untitled.png

**Gmail Inbox can't access** https://i.ibb.co/0Qysk4S/Untitled5.png

**Note** : I can't post imges StackOverflow show messenge "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

**Could u help me ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve the problem.

I let change Firewall filter rule in Action accept & check other website network connect add to address lists.

[This my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eP8O.png)